# Why isn't the compiler generating an error "lvalue required"?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

As per my understanding, in the line marked as 'line 2' of the below code, the expression `(*ptr)++` should generate "lvalue required" error because `*ptr` evaluates to a constant value of `i=1`, which is not lvalue?

So why is the program working successfully? Or am I somewhere wrong in my concepts? If yes, please enlighten me on this.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *ptr = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        *(ptr + i) = i;

    printf("%d ", *ptr++);   //line 1
    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++); //line 2 
    printf("%d ", *ptr);     //line 3
    printf("%d ", *++ptr);   //line 4
    printf("%d ", ++*ptr);   //line 5
}
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: `*ptr` is an lvalue. So I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `*ptr` is an `int`; it can be incremented.

Comment: "*`*ptr` evaluates to a constant value of `i=1`*": I'm not sure I understand this statement. Can you explain?

Comment: @Cornstalks i mean "*ptr" is value at address stored in ptr, which is equal to 1, so is 1++ valid?

Comment: What about `int i = 0; i++;`. If `i` is 0, then is `0++` valid? The answer is of course no, `0++` (and `1++`) are not valid. `++` is not applied to the *value*, it's applied to the *object* (in this case `i`, or in your case, the object pointed to by `*ptr`).

Comment: @Cornstalks ok , now i got it. i would have green ticked this if this was an answer. :)

Comment: @codeluv: There, I made it an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having a misconception. result of `(*ptr)` **is** lvalue, upon which the post increment operator can be applied.

So, in your case,

```
 printf("%d ", (*ptr)++); //line 2
```

is fine.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.3.2, *Address and indirection operators*, <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.**

FWIW, if `*ptr` would not be a lvalue, you would have got error for writing something like `*ptr = 5` also, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What about `int i = 0; i++;`. If `i` is 0, then is `0++` valid? The answer is of course no, `0++` (and `1++`) are not valid. `++` is not applied to the *value*, it's applied to the *object* (in this case `i`, or in your case, the object pointed to by `*ptr`).

Answer (score 1):

An lvalue is  something that refers to someplace in memory that can/does hold a value.So if `*ptr=10;` then `*ptr` is `lvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 42;
    int *ptr = &i;       /* ptr points to i */
    (*ptr)++;            /* you increment the pointed value */
    printf("%d", i);     /* and there is a proof: 43 is displayed */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: taking into account how sometimes undefined behavior leads to expected results I wouldn't consider `43 is displayed` a `proof` ;-)